# ngMessage not working in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, using-directives

I am making a simple validation of required, but unable to find ng-Message working on wrong entry or on clicking submit. Can someone help me out where am I wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Script Files --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form name="form1" id="form1" novalidate> 
        <input type="text" name="age" ng-minlength="3" required/> 
        <div ng-messages="form1.age.$error" ng-show="(form1.age.$error.required || form1.age.$error.minlength) && (form1.age.$touched || form1.$submitted) " >
            <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
            <div ng-message="minlength">Length is too less</div>

        </div>
        <a data-ng-click="submit(form1.$invalid)">Click</a> 
    </form>

    <script>
    //module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);
    //controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        var submit = function(invalid){
            if(invalid) return;
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add angular message js file. //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-messages.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-message is not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746963/ng-message-is-not-showing)

Comment: That question is completely different. Mine is much more simpler and related to validation of 1 single input on base of $touched and integer manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your age input has no `ng-model`. Validation alá minlength only works if `ng-model` is present:

```
<input type="text" name="age" ng-model="age" ng-minlength="3" required/>
```

This is due to how validators work. You'll notice ng-model is not set, when $valid is false. There's always a hint in the docs as well: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMinlength

Also `ng-model` doesn't need to be the same as the field name.